# Mail Server with javax.mail and CentOS

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I have a Java Program that was installed on an old Ubuntu machine and sent mail using javax.mail. However, that machine went down and I am now running the same Java app in a new CentOS machine.

However, I get an error "MessagingException: 501 Syntax: HELO hostname" when trying to send an email using mail.smtp.host = 127.0.0.1.

My guess is that the mailserver is not yet activated in this CentOS.

How would I go about configuring a mail server that javax.mail can use?

Thank you

Answer (score 6):

Your machine host name must be mapped in `/etc/hosts` file.

Example:
Console shows: `linux#` 
and `cat /etc/hostname` shows

```
linux.mydomain.com
```

Then edit your hosts file running as `root` . `vi /etc/hosts`

```
127.0.0.1  localhost linux linux.mydomain.com
```

Good detailed info can be found here: https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/CONFKB/Sending+Email+Fails+Due+to+501+Syntax%3A+HELO+Hostname+Error

Answer (score 3):

I encountered the same issue "MessagingException: 501 Syntax: HELO hostname" when sending out email with Spring MailSender. What works for me is to add in extra property "mail.smtp.localhost" under javaMailProperties like below:

```
    <!-- JAVA MAIL -->
<bean id="mailSender" class="org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl">
    <property name="host" value="" />
    <property name="port" value="25" />
    <property name="protocol" value="smtp" />
    <property name="username" value="" />
    <property name="password" value="" />
    <property name="javaMailProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="mail.smtps.auth">true</prop>
            <prop key="mail.smtps.starttls.enable">true</prop>
            <prop key="mail.smtps.debug">true</prop>
            <prop key="mail.smtp.localhost">localhost</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the naming service on the new machine is not properly configured and Java can't find the host name of the machine.  The SMTP HELO command needs to include the host name.  The server is complaining because it's missing.  Turn on JavaMail Session debugging and you can see the actual command this is sent.  You can work around this host configuration problem by setting the JavaMail property mail.smtp.localhost to be the host name you want to use in the HELO command.

Comment: I followed a guide on the Internet for fixing this problem that claimed I should go to the /etc/hosts file and add a mapping of 127.0.0.1 to the domain name of the machine. And so I did. Still didn't work after. Is this what you meant?

Comment: Does the machine have a static IP address or does it get its IP address from DHCP?  If it has a static IP address, that should be in /etc/hosts with the machine name.  If it gets it from DHCP, reverse DNS lookups of that IP address need to return a valid host name.  You probably need to talk to your local networking expert to get all this set up correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You need to run `sendmail`. See [here](http://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/5.1/Deployment_Guide/s3-email-mta-sendmail-default.html) for more info. Configuring `sendmail` can be a chore and you may want to take the configuration `sendmail.cf` from the old machine if possible.

I suspect (also) that you should have some central MTA (mail transport agent) set up, such that all machines in your enterprise use this, rather than running one per host. i.e. *not* using `localhost`.

Comment: I tried connecting to port 25 using telnet and sending a sample email, and this email is sent perfectly. Does this mean the Java app should also work?

Answer (score 0):

In my case etc/hostname was susetest(and not linux.company.com)

Modified etc/hosts from 127.0.0.1 localhost to 127.0.0.1 localhost susetest(also after localhost make sure to use tab, when modifying the file)

Make sure to save changes, postfix stop, postfix start to restart SMTP server.

Should work fine.

(adding properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.localhost", "ourcompany.com"); to the properties also solved the problem, but workaround should not be the fix, when you can find the root cause, even if it takes days in my case)

Comment: Reason for downvoting?!