# HELO command failed, output: Syntax: HELO hostname

Tags: php, email, sendmail

I need to use a local mail server in order to send mail via SMTP.

I have the IP of the mail server, something like : 192.168.X.X. But when I try to send mail using it I have the following error :

```
HELO command failed, output: Syntax: HELO hostname
```

To be honest this is not really a field I'm goot at, so I'm pretty confused

Comment: Can you provide more information? How does your code work? What exactly does the HELO Command look like you are giving the server? The current error just says, that the command you give is not within the allowed syntax. Without the command for us to see, we can barely help.

Comment: Duplicate from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13840444/mail-server-with-javax-mail-and-centos/29220367